# Как сделать поиск доменов?

Tags: php

Привет, возможно кто знает как сделать поиск доменов как на этом сайте

http://who.pho.to/imvu_mobile_credits.html

?

То есть вводишь keywords, а потом вылазят список сайтов по запросу.

Возможно кто знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по результатам, ключевые слова ищутся в title, description и keywords сайтов. То есть по сути этот поисковик принципиально не отличается от других, просто у него тематическая база доменов, индекс строится по ограниченным областям и не строится по страницам, отличным от главной. Плюс - во внутреннюю базу кроме  индекса складываются скриншот и данные whois.

Глубже не копал, но вроде это и всё.

Стало быть, ответ на вопрос "*как сделать поиск доменов как на этом сайте?*" простой: точно так же, как и любой другой поисковик, но с учётом ограничений по тематическим URL и областям поиска.

Comment: Возможно вы знаете откуда он собирает такой список доменов по запросам? Возможно есть какие-то публичные поиска типа google, bing или еще какие? Я просто не могу найти сайт, где можно чекать не ограниченно по KEYWORDS и чтобы потом отображались домены по запросам

Comment: А что мешает использовать результаты того же гугла? Получили выдачу по ключевым словам, проверили description/keywords/tilte у доменов, OK - занесли в свою базу.

Comment: Хм, а можно как-то в примере? А то не совсем понял(((

Comment: Э... Что тут можно не понять?

1) Ищем в гугле, к примеру, "VISA".

2) Выдаётся 10 ссылок, из них 5 - на уникальных доменах

3) Идём по этим 5 доменам и парсим контент. Есть в нужных областях слово "VISA"? Да - наш клиент, складываем домен в свою базу.

4) Периодически повторяем пункты 1-3 для поиска новых доменов

5) Так же, периодически, проходимся по существующим в базе доменам и выполняем пункт 3. Пропали ключевые слова из нужных мест - удаляем из базы (помечаем как проблемный и замораживаем для индексации, делаем что-то ещё - в общем, творчески)

Comment: Ну для этого нужна база, а это много места на сайте надо... Мне бы хотелось без базы данных

Comment: Для любого поисковика нужна база. Или вы что, думаете, что поиска в гугле хватит? Нет, конечно, это только самый первый и самый простой этап: сбор тематических URL. А дальше начинается самое интересное. Но это уже не сюда - читать как устроены индексаторы поисковиков в принципе. Или переформулируйте задачу, потому что "как на том сайте" без баз (да и на таком уровне знаний) у вас точно не получится.

Comment: Не согласен, можно сайты на подобии поисковиков делать и без базы данных... Сам такие делаю на основе api. А про SEO норм все у меня. Мне просто нужны урлы, откуда брать, а с остальным сам разберусь)

Comment: "На чьём-то подобии" и "как на том сайте" - разницу видите? Впрочем, такому серьёзному специалисту мне больше нечего советовать...

Answer (score 0):

Без базы данных? 
Ну тогда подключаем абстрактное мышление:
Наш скрипт, который будет проверять по слову запросу обращается к тому же гуглу, парсит килотонны сайтов, выдаёт, и так каждый раз. 
Да у вас сервер раньше умрет. 
С БД всё гораздо удобнее будет, ибо рано или поздно запросов к сторонним сервисам будет меньше, соберется собственная база, с которой будет намного удобнее работать, и скорость выдачи результатов будет намного меньше, и нагрузка на сервер - так же.
Ну или же спарсите базу доменов и так же бегайте по ней, уже не используя сторонние сервисы.